# T functions arising from derivatives of incomplete Gamma function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, gamma-function

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#cite_note-29) the derivatives of the incomplete gamma functions are described via:
$$
T(m,s,x) = G_{m-1,\,m}^{\,m,\,0} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} 0, 0, \dots, 0 \\ s-1, -1, \dots, -1 \end{matrix} \; \right| \, x \right)
$$

I am interested in $T(4,1,x)$ for $x$ large in terms of how it scales with $x$.
For example $xT(3,1,x) = E_1(x)$, is there a similar simplification for $T(4,1,x)$?
There exists an expansion for $|x|<1$ and in Geddes et al paper it is mentioned that an analytic continuation of the series expansion is possible when proving that $T$ satisfied a differential equation. Yet even from the expansion, that does involve a Meijer-G function in turn, I can not tell how $T$ scales with $x$.

**Reference**

K. O. Geddes, M. L. Glasser, R. A. Moore, T. C. Scott, "Evaluation of classes of definite integrals involving elementary functions via differentiation of special functions", Applicable Algebra in Engineering, Communication and Computing,  1, No. 2, 149-165 (1990), DOI:[10.1007/BF01810298](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01810298), [MR1325519](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1325519), [Zbl 0726.33015](https://zbmath.org/0726.33015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Ga}{\Gamma} $We have
\begin{equation*}
    T(4,1,x)\sim t(x):=e^{-x}/x^3 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
as $x\to\infty$.

Indeed, from formulas (29) and (30) of the linked paper we get
$$T(4,1,x)=\frac{g_2(x)-2 g_1(x) \ln x+e^{-x} \ln^2 x}{2
   x},$$
where
$$g_k(x):=\int_x^\infty\ln^k u\,e^{-u}\,du.$$
Using now repeatedly integration by parts to obtain enough terms of the asymptotics of $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$, we get \eqref{1} -- see details on this at the end of this answer.

---

Here is the graph $\{(x,\frac{T(4,1,x)}{t(x)})\colon20\le x\le200\}$:

[image]

---

**Details:** Let $l$ denote a function of the form $\ln^p$ for some real $p$ or any of its derivatives, of any order. Integrating by parts, for all real $x>1$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    g(x):=\int_x^\infty l(u) e^{-u}\,du=l(x)e^{-x}+\int_x^\infty l'(u) e^{-u}\,du
\end{equation*}
and hence, by induction, for any natural $k$,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
g(x)&=(l(x)+l'(x)+\cdots+l^{(k-1)}(x))e^{-x}+\int_x^\infty l^{(k)}(u) e^{-u}\,du \\ 
&=(l(x)+l'(x)+\cdots+l^{(k-1)}(x)+l^{(k)}(x)(1+o(1)))e^{-x}  
\end{aligned}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
(as $x\to\infty$). The latter equality in \eqref{2} follows by the l'Hospital rule, because $(\ln^p)^{(k)}(x)\asymp x^{-k}\ln^{p-1}x$ and hence $r(x):=l^{(k+1)}(x)/l^{(k)}(x)\to0$. $\Big($Indeed,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\Big(\int_x^\infty l^{(k)}(u) e^{-u}\,du\Big)'_x}
    {\big(l^{(k)}(x) e^{-x}\big)'_x}\
    =\frac1{1-r(x)}\to1, 
\end{equation*}
where ${}'_x$ denotes the differentiation in $x$.$\Big)$

So, by \eqref{2} with $k=3$ and $g\in\{g_1,g_2\}$,
\begin{equation*}
e^x g_1(x)=\ln x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2+o(1)}{x^3}, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
e^x g_2(x)=\ln^2 x+\frac{2 \ln x}{x}-\frac{2 \ln x}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x^2}
    +\frac{(4+o(1)) \ln x}{x^3},  
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
e^x T(4,1,x)=\frac{x+o(\ln x)}{x^4}\sim 1/x^3. \quad\Box 
\end{equation*}

Comment: I would be very happy about the details, because my initial goal is to understand $g_2(x)$ and I've hoped that this could be achieved via $T(4,1,x)$.

Comment: I have now added the details.

Comment: Thanks @Iosif! I followed your derivation, yet I wonder how it works out that you truncate the integral up to $\mathcal{o}(1)$ while the full asymptotic expansion of the integral diverges (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789344/int-n-infty-e-u-log2u-du-with-variable-start-n).

Comment: @user18722294 : I never used or mentioned a full asymptotic expansion. As stated in the answer, I just used the partial expansion (2), with $k=3$ and $g\in\{g_1,g_2\}$. Details of the straightforward calculations are presented in the pdf image of a Mathematica notebook at  
https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZ8jgrVZ8RYQhDbdjG0VlsdOHpbdrYJ6XaPX . Please let me know if anything here still seems unclear..

Comment: I accepted it,  thanks a lot!

Comment: could you elaborate on how you used l'Hôpital to obtain the asymptotic behaviour of the k-the derivative of $\ln^p$? @Isofi Pinelis

Comment: @user18722294 : I did not use the l'Hospital rule to obtain the asymptotic behavior of the $k$th derivative of $\ln^p$ -- the latter can be obtained by induction on $k$. I used the l'Hospital rule and the asymptotic behavior of the $k$th derivative of $\ln^p$ to obtain the second equality in (2).

Comment: Pinels alright, can you specify in which order you consider the limit $x \to \infty$, before or inside the integral? If latter, why is it justified?

Comment: @user18722294 : I have added further details on this.